# Can I use the plural pronoun "they" for countries?

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns

In the following, is it correct to use the plural pronoun **they** (along with the plural verb) to refer back to Japan?

> Will Japan get back up if **they** experience another recession?

Comment: I suspect when people use _they_ for a country it means they are thinking of the people rather than the country. You could argue whether it is the country or its inhabitants which experiences a recession.

Comment: No, in formal writing I would only use "it".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a country can be treated singular or plural or even feminine gender.

If we are talking about a country, we usually use the singular number and the pronoun becomes she or it.

If we are talking about the government, we may use the plural number. So we can use the pronoun they.

> Will Japan get back up if they experience another recession?

As per the link we can say:

> Japan are a great power in the world.

The sentence is not wrong. so **they** in the above sentence is not wrong.

In the sentence, we are talking about the government of Japan. So it is treated as plural and the pronoun "they" is used.

The verb also takes the plural form

I herewith enclose two links that clarify your question.

http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/1535_questionanswer/page51.shtml

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/223658/its-vs-their-country

Comment: Historically, Germany was "The Fatherland" and Russia "The Motherland" - so masculine pronouns are not unheard of.

Comment: @Davo. A good point to learn from you

Comment: The page you linked to does not discuss pronouns.

Comment: What complicates this issue is the names of some countries. For example, most people are likely to use the plural form after such countries as ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA, BOSNIA AND HERZEGOVINA, MARSHALL ISLANDS and numerous other examples in which the country's name comprises two or more elements.

Comment: Let us limit the scope of the question to single-element country names. Would you think "they" is a correct pronoun for names like "Japan"?

Comment: Could you please show the reason the down voter? have you not seen the links?

Answer (score 1):

Use "it" in most contexts.

Use "they" only when "Japan" is standing in for "a group of Japanese people or things".

> Japan are ahead at halftime in the football match. They have scored twice!

Here "Japan" means "the Japanese national football team", which is a group of people, and so may be treated as plural.

In most other contexts use "it" and "is". In your example you should use "it".